# Assigning *&array to a pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, assignment-operator

The following excerpt is from [Harbinson, Steele C: A Reference Manual (5th Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013089592X). According to the book the two assignments to `p` are equivalent.

**7.5.6 Address Operator**

```
int a[10], *p;
p = a; p = *&a;
```

Yet, according to the C faq [Question 6.12](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryvsadr.html) `a` is of type pointer to `int` whereas `&a` is of type pointer to array of `int`.

So we should get a type error in the second assignment `p = *&a` because we are trying to assign an array of `int` to a pointer.

Why is the assignment `p = *&a` correct?

Comment: I do not understand where the confusion is - if `&a` is pointer to array of `int`, then *&a is array of `int`, which is of type pointer to `int`, which is the type of `p`.

Comment: Please don't add _post links_ in the question body. Any good answer will quote /cite references anyway.

Comment: Unary `*` is the inverse of unary `&`, so `*&a == a`, and therefore if `p = a` is legal (which it is), then so is `p = *&a`.

Comment: "*`a` is of type pointer to `int`*", no `a` is an array, namely of type `int[10]`.

Comment: @reproduktor: `*&a` is indeed an array of `int`, However, its type is `int[10]`, not a "pointer to `int`". Type `int[10]` *decays* to `int *` later in this context.

Comment: @AnT: You are of course right, I should have written 'decays to' rather than 'is of'. My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.3.2, *Address and indirection operators*,

> The unary `*` operator denotes indirection. [....] If the operand has type *‘‘pointer to type’’*, the result has type *‘‘type’’*. [....]

So, for `p = *&a;`,

- `&a` is a pointer to "array of `int`s".
- `*&a` is an array type.

Now, when used in RHS of assignment, an array type decays to pointer to the first element of the array, an `int *`.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.3.2.1

> Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the
>   unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has
>   type *‘‘array of type’’* is converted to an expression with type *‘‘pointer to type’’* that points
>   to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. [...]

Hence, there's no warning/ error reported.

Comment: @Roland Well, the official doc is not _for free_. _Hint: Please do a google search with n1570, hope that helps_ :)

Answer (score 1):

When `*&` comes together then it is not evaluated. `p = *&a;` is equivqlent to `p = a;`. `*` and `&` nullify the effects of each other.

Comment: Sir, I know it happens for `&*`, is it the same for `*&` also? §6.5.3.2/p3

Comment: @SouravGhosh; Yes, final result will be the same.