# Integer from pointer warning

Tags: c

I have I problem. I get 2 warnings from console, but I dont know what's wrong with my code. Can you have look?
Program suppose to show lines with at least 11 characters and 4 numbers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int main()
{
    char line[200];

    printf("Enter a string: \n");
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line),stdin))
    {
        int numberAlpha = 0;
        int numberDigit = 0;
        if(isalpha(line)) numberAlpha++;
        else if(isdigit(line)) numberDigit++;

        if(numberAlpha+numberDigit>10 && numberDigit>3) printf("%s \n", line);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at how `isalpha` and `isdigit` are supposed to be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i got something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int main()
{
    char line[200];

    printf("Enter a string: \n");
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line),stdin))
    {
        int numberAlpha = 0;
        int numberDigit = 0;
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<strlen(line); i++){
            if(isalpha(line[i])) numberAlpha++;
            else if(isdigit(line[i])) numberDigit++;
        }

        if(numberAlpha+numberDigit>10 && numberDigit>3) printf("%s \n", line);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now the question is, if it is passible to make it first accepts data and then display only those line which follows the if statment. Now it shows line just after input it.

Answer (score 1):

[`isalpha()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isalpha.3.html) and [`isdigit()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isalpha.3.html) functions take an `int`. But you are passing a `char*` i.e. the array `line` gets converted into a pointer to its first element (see: [What is array decaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying)). That's what the compiler complains about. You need to loop over `line` to find the number of digits and alphabets in it.

Also note that [`fgets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html) will read in the newline character if `line` has space. So, you need to trim it out before counting.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char line[200];

    printf("Enter a string: \n");
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line),stdin))
    {
        int numberAlpha = 0;
        int numberDigit = 0;

        line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = 0; // Remove the trailing newline, if any.

        for (size_t i = 0; line[i]; i++) {
        if(isalpha((unsigned char)line[i])) numberAlpha++;
        else if((unsigned char)isdigit(line[i])) numberDigit++;
        }

        printf("alpha: %d, digits:%d \n", numberAlpha, numberDigit);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both  [`isalpha()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/isalpha) and [`isdigit()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/isdigit) takes an `int`, not a `char *, as argument`.

In your code, by passing the array name as the argument, you're essentially passing a `char *` [(*array name decays to the pointer to the first element when used as function argument*)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39676934/2173917), so, you're getting the warning.

You need to loop over the individual elements of `line` and pass them to the functions.

That said, just a suggestion, for hosted environment, `int main()` should be `int main(void)` to conform to the standard.

Answer (score 1):

`isalpha` and `isdigit` are supposed to test if a `char` taken as `int` (a `char` can be safely converted to an `int`) is the encoding of an alphanumeric or digit character. You pass a `char` array, not an individual `char`. You need to test each `char` of the string you got, so you need a loop as:

```
for (int i=0; i<strlen(line); i++) {
    if (isalpha(line[i])) numberAlpha++;
    ...
}
```

It is better to compute the length once:

```
int length = strlen(line);
for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
    ...
}
```

You may also use a pointer to move along the string:

```
for (char *ptr = line; *ptr!=`\0`; ptr++) {
    if (isalpha(*ptr)) ...
    ...
}
```